# Wrapped flexbox element overflowing its parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to structure my entries column-wise and then, if no further vertical space is available, wrap them to the next "column".

My code:

```
<div style="width:800px;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;flex-direction:column;background:rgb(230, 230, 230);height:300px;">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;">Thats a short text.</div>
  </div>
[...]
  <div style="border:1px solid red;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I expect:**
The wrapped flex element just fills the remaining space.

**What I get**
The wrapped flex element overflows its parent container.

[image: The actual output]

I tried several combinations of flex-grow, flex-shrink, word-wrap  and so on, but without a success.
Although there are mass of threads regarding flexbox issues, I haven't found a thread that deals with my problem. Is this really a limitation of flexbox or did I miss something?

Comment: Try to give `max-width: 800px`  and give the width: 100%  to the items

Comment: You have to give the child-elements a max-width(let's say 50%)

Comment: If you have fixed content then you can simply use grid with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is probably overkill for this depending on what you are trying to do. For example, you could just use [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

```html
<div style="width:800px;columns:2;background:rgb(230, 230, 230);height:300px;">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="border:1px solid blue;">Thats a short text.</div>
  </div>
[...]
  <div style="border:1px solid red;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is my solution now. To know how many columns I need, I use javascript and check if the elements have enough space in this column. If not, I increase the number of columns. Works quite well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **margin-right: auto;** on all the containers of short text or you can use CSS class or SASS variable to not repeat code.  [Flexbox1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpjGp.jpg)

However, if you want to vertically align the below Lorem paragraph too, you can see flexbox-vertical1 where I used 2 different containers (container1 for short text and container2 for Lorem paragraph). I removed flex-wrap from parent container and added this to container1  style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">

[Flexbox-vertical1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghBI.jpg)

Added flex growth, shrink, & width too in flexbox-vertical2, but not ideal unless you know the percentage of space the containers take.  I removed flex-wrap from parent container. Added this to container1 style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 0 0 70%".

[Flexbox-vertical2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA5cs.jpg)